# MySQL returning rows that don't equal values in a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM default_albums da
                               INNER JOIN default_album_hc_connect d ON d.albums_id = da.album_id_da
                               INNER JOIN default_hottest_categories dhc ON dhc.id = d.hottest_categories_id
                               WHERE dhc.is_hottest = 'Yes'");
```

The above is my current query. I have an array called results that is being pulled in from an ajax post. How can I take that array and return rows that don't equal the values from that array?

Answer (score 1):

What about the `NOT IN` condition ?

```
" (...)
WHERE (...)
    AND whatever NOT IN (\"" . implode('", "', $array) . "\")";
```

Comment: `Unknown column '37173375051af44ce29816' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM default_albums da INNER JOIN default_album_hc_connect d ON d.albums_id = da.album_id_da INNER JOIN default_hottest_categories dhc ON dhc.id = d.hottest_categories_id WHERE dhc.is_hottest = 'Yes' AND da.album_id_da NOT IN (37173375051af44ce29816, 185421235851af446a1be2e, 70884918151af4500e28bb)` - this is my error.

Comment: Thanks man, for some reason though it's still returning all of the albums and not only the ones that don't equal up.

Comment: ` $results = $this->input->post('ids');
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM default_albums da
          INNER JOIN default_album_hc_connect d ON d.albums_id = da.album_id_da
            INNER JOIN default_hottest_categories dhc ON dhc.id = d.hottest_categories_id
           WHERE dhc.is_hottest = 'Yes' AND da.album_id_da NOT IN (\".implode(', ', $results).\")");
 foreach($query->result() as $row) {
  echo $row->album_name;
 }`

Comment: I would assume you also need to take out `dhc.is_hottest='Yes'` from the query.